# Expression Engine Does not Work Without index.php? - "?" always required

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, expressionengine

We are facing an issue to access pages from website.

As below url is being built
https://www.website.com/index.php/about/ensembles/concert-band

But It always shows home page only.

However when I append "?" (after index.php) in url, it shows the actual page.
Like: https://www.website.com/index.php?/about/ensembles/concert-band

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue to access pages without "?" - Is there any settings into expression engine to enable/disable? Currently, we have hosted on Ubuntu & PHP5. - We tried with Force Querystring enable/disable but did not work anyhow. Also we tried with below .htaccess, but no luck

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?$1 [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Please suggest/advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the question mark

```
/index.php?/$1
```